# How can I call this method for retrieved data in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, methods

I'm working on a program that allows you to select a customer ID from a dropdown box. Once the customer ID is selected, the customer's information is pulled from a CSV file and displayed in textboxes.

The phone number information is unformatted, but I want it to be displayed formatted (ex. (800)674-3452). I have written a method for this, but I'm not sure how to call it. Can you please help?

-Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm still learning.

```
    private void idBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try // catch errors
        {
            string selectedCustomer; // variable to hold chosen customer ID
            selectedCustomer = idBox.Text; // retrieve the customer number selected

            chosenIndex = 0;
            bool found = false; // variable if customer ID was found
            while (!found && chosenIndex < allData.Length) // loop through the 2D array
            {
                if (allData[chosenIndex, 0] == selectedCustomer) // make sure it's the right customer
                {
                    found = true; // Yes (true) found the correct customer
                }

                chosenIndex++; // add one row 
            }
            chosenIndex -= 1; // subtract one because add 1 before exiting while

            /* 0 = customer ID
             * 1 = name
             * 2 = address
             * 3 = city
             * 4 = state
             * 5 = zip
             * 6 = phone
             * 7 = email
             * 8 = charge account - yes/no
             * 9 = good standing - yes/no
             */
            nameBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 1]; // put name in nameBox
            addressBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 2]; // put address in addressBox
            cityBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 3]; // put city in cityBox
            stateBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 4]; //puts state in stateBox
            zipBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 5]; // puts zip in zipBox
            phoneBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 6]; // puts phone number in phoneBox
            emailBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 7]; // puts email in emailBox
            if (allData[chosenIndex, 8] == "Yes") // check if charge account
            {
                yesChargeRadio.Checked = true; // true if Yes
            }
            else // otherwise
            {
                noChargeRadio.Checked = true; // true if No
            }
            if (allData[chosenIndex, 9] == "Yes") // check for good standing
            {
                yesStandingRadio.Checked = true; // true if Yes
            }
            else // otherwise
            {
                noStandingRadio.Checked = true; // true if No
            }
        }
        catch (Exception errorInfo) // catch error
        {
            MessageBox.Show("errors: " + errorInfo, "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); // error message
        }

    }
```

Here is the method(s) to check the length and format:

```
    private bool numberCheck(string str)
    {
        const int NUMBER_LENGTH = 10;
        bool valid = true;

        if (str.Length == NUMBER_LENGTH)
        {
            foreach (char ch in str)
            {
                if (!char.IsDigit(ch))
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
    private void formatPhone(ref string str)
    {
        str = str.Insert(0, "(");
        str = str.Insert(4, ")");
        str = str.Insert(8, "-");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done with your code. What you need to do is, before you set your `phoneBox.Text` you can call the method as below:

```
if(numberCheck(allData[chosenIndex, 6]))
{

    formatPhone(ref allData[chosenIndex, 6]);
}

phoneBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 6];
```

As you have your method with ref parameter, the formatted text will be updated in your arary and you can then assign it to your `phoneBox`

Comment: Aha! Thanks that worked great. It's always the simple things....smh. Thank you so much

Comment: I have updated the answer, just to include the `numberCheck` method.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what part specifically you're asking about: you call methods you define just like the static methods IsDigit or MessageBox.Show, except you do not need to prefix the method name with a name and then a period because the method is part of the object calling it.

So, for example if I had a method:

```
public void ShowSomething()
{
     MessageBox.Show("stuff");
}
```

From within the class, I could call it like this:

```
ShowSomething();
```

To pass parameters, I would list them in the parenthesis, as you do with MessageBox.Show, for example.

You can use the value a method like `numberCheck` returns as any other boolean, so you could do any of these:

```
bool b = numberCheck(someString);
if (numberCheck(someString))
{
    //Do something, like displaying the phone number
}
```

This MSDN document might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Comment: I tried this, but I'm doing something wrong:                 phoneBox.Text = allData[chosenIndex, 6]; // puts phone number in phoneBox
                phoneFix = phoneBox.Text.Trim();
                bool b = numberCheck(allData[chosenIndex, 6])
                    if (numberCheck(allData[chosenIndex, 6]))
                    {
                        formatPhone(phoneBox.Text)
                    }

Comment: Sorry if that's hard to read. I didn't realize I couldn't paste the code in the comment section.

Comment: Is there a specific error message you're getting? What is it?

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? :

```
.......
phoneBox.Text = numberCheck(allData[chosenIndex, 6]) ? 
                formatPhone(allData[chosenIndex, 6]) : 
                allData[chosenIndex, 6];
.......
private string formatPhone(string str)
{
    str = str.Insert(0, "(");
    str = str.Insert(4, ")");
    str = str.Insert(8, "-");
    return str;
}
```

Codes above will check validity of phone data, if it is valid set `phoneBox.Text` to formatted phone number, else set `phoneBox.Text` to raw unformatted phone data.

[For reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) in case you're not familiar with ternary operator (`?`).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and got an error on the 2nd line - "The best overloaded method match for ....formatPhone(ref string) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: check `formatPhone()` function in this answer, I updated it slightly because it won't work well as posted in question.

Comment: Got it figured out. Thank your for your answer!